# putting an hebrew at mysql

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, mysqli, hebrew

i trying to put hebrew at mysql DB and i read all the answer and it didn't work.
i can put hebrew value with php my admin so the problem must be at the script.
i try use:

1.header().

2.set name utf-8.

3.mysql_set_charset().

```
<?php   
$cate_name=$_POST['cate_name'];


$query="INSERT INTO project_food_cate (name) VALUES(?)"; 

$connector=new MySQLi("localhost","[redacted]","[redacted]","users");

        /*this code need to put the a privalage to use hebrew values for the rows*/
    header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8');
    mysql_query("SET character_set_client=utf8"); 
    mysql_query("SET character_set_connection=utf8"); 
    mysql_query("SET character_set_database=utf8"); 
    mysql_query("SET character_set_results=utf8"); 
    mysql_query("SET character_set_server=utf8"); 
    mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

    mysqli_set_charset('utf-8',$connector); 



    $charset = mysql_client_encoding($connector);
        echo "The current character set is:".$charset."\n"; //not giving a     value.

    /***************************************************************/


if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "error has been happend";
        exit();
    }


$stmt=$connector-> prepare($query);
$stmt-> bind_param("s",$cate_name);
$stmt-> execute();
echo $stmt-> affected_rows." has enter to this DB";

$stmt->free();
$stmt->close();
?>
```

Comment: You're mixing `mysqli` and `mysql`.

Comment: if you're using mysqli then the mysql_* functions aren't going to do anything for you; they're from a different library.

Comment: What charset is defined for the field `name` in table `project_food_cate`? also, please note that the `header()` you are sending should state `utf-8` and not `utf8`.

Comment: Try `echo`ing the posted variable and see if the posted data displays ok, then you will know of you have an HTML encoding problem.  Make sure that your browser understands that it should display and encode in UTF-8 in the browser's encoding settings.

Comment: i do all what you recommend me to do .

Comment: what you think i need to put at name field as charset? i try to put utf-8 unicode , hebrew-bin and nothing work, when i try hebrew bin it display numbers and letters instead question marks

Comment: i also try to echo the variable , its return me the hebrew value.

Comment: i try to re-run the code and make a lot of checking and i found that my charset is "latin1" , anyone know how to change it?

Answer (score 1):

mysqli_set_charset() should be 'utf8' not 'utf-8'. 
Also I believe it should be mysqli_set_charset($connector, 'utf8');